# Check if everything (including video) is loaded in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, loading

I have a Vue project that is getting a little large due to an embedded html5 video and am wondering how to tackle the loading issue for this site.

Is there a way to know if everything is loaded in Vue so I can show a loading screen before everything is ready? And does this loading take into account of assets loading like images, videos, etc?

Comment: The video shouldn't prevent the site from loading the rest of the webpage's assets concurrently, so I don't really think there is any solution to this non-problem (as far as the video is concerned).

Comment: Because the video is going to be a background running video, I would hope to have everything loaded first before showing the page so it won't look jerky or hanged if the connection is below average. But also, this got me to thinking about preloaders in Vue, how does Vue handle loading?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to wait for the rest of the webpage to finish loading before displaying the video, you can wait until the window has loaded ([`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) event) and then display the video via `v-if`.

Here's some additional things to consider (you're using webpack, right?):

### Code splitting

If your JS bundle is getting too big, you can split it into smaller chunks and the webpack runtime will download the chunks asynchronously on demand.

I like to split my vendor code into a separate chunk, as well as split off some router components like this:

```es6
{
  path: 'foo',
  component: () => import('./components/foo.vue'),
}
```

See [Code Splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) (Webpack docs) and [Async Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Async-Components) (Vue docs) for more info.

### Loading page

Your webpage will initially appear blank while the browser is downloading the HTML and JS assets before the Vue app has been bootstrapped. During this time, you can display whatever plain HTML content you want, then mount the root Vue component over the loading HTML.

```js
const App = {
  template: '<div>My App</div>',
};

function bootstrap() {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render: h => h(App),
  });
}

// Simulate loading
setTimeout(bootstrap, 2000);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

@keyframes loading-anim {
  from { opacity: 1; }
  to { opacity: 0.3; }
}

.loading {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #888;
  letter-spacing: -0.05em;
  font-weight: bold;
  animation: loading-anim 1s ease-in-out alternate infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <!-- Put whatever loading HTML content here -->
  <div class="loading">LOADING</div>
</div>

<script src="https://rawgit.com/vuejs/vue/dev/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I was actually trying out the load event, but can't seem to make the window's listener communicate with Vue. How do you get it to change Vue's data?